# How to remove shadow around windows in GNOME

Tags: gnome, gtk

How can I remove the shadow around windows in GNOME 45 in a way that it will never be reapplied again even if a new theme has them?

[image]

Comment: I have Gnome running in Ubuntu and no shadows (I removed them).  However a new theme started things fresh and I do not think can stop shadows in a new theme. Set it again.